# Prove that $A' \subseteq B$ if and only if $A \cup B = U$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Consider subsets $A$, $B$ and $C$ of the universe $U$

> Prove that $A^c \subseteq B$ if and only if $A \cup B = U$

I know that there are two directions for the problem:

1. If $A^c \subseteq B$ then $A \cup B = U$

   1.1 Suppose $A^c \subseteq B$ then prove that $A \cup B \subseteq U$

   1.2 Suppose $A^c \subseteq B$ then prove that $U \subseteq A \cup B$
2. If $A \cup B = U$ then $A^c \subseteq B$

---

Attempt:

**1.1** Suppose $A^c \subseteq B$. Let $x \in A^c$ then we know $x\in B$ so $x\in A\cup B$. Since universal set $U$ contains all set, then $A \cup B \subseteq U.$

**1.2** Suppose $A^c \subseteq B$. Let $x \in A^c$ then we know $x\in B$. As well $x\in U$ --- we know that $U = A \cup A^c$. 
If $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup B$. 
If $x \in A^c$, then $x \in B$ since $A^c \subseteq B$. Then, $x \in A\cup B$. 
So in either cases, $x \in A \cup B$. Therefore $U \subseteq A\cup B$.

**2.** I'm not sure how to approach this direction. Could I do something similar to part *1.2* and split into cases of $A$ and $A^c$ from $U$ and argue?

Comment: If you take any $x \in A^C$, you know $x \in U$. What does $x \in U$ mean here?

Comment: @babemcnuggets I'm not sure if I understand your question. I'm assuming you are asking about 1.2, I wrote $x\in U$ because I want to talk about $U = A \cup A^c$. I understand this is kind of unnecessary but it's just for my own understand and clarity.

Comment: Oh no, I meant this for 2). Your 1) looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A\cup B = U$. By De morgan's law, one has $A^c \cap B^c = U^c = \varnothing$. This means $A^c \subset B$.